# is that possible to use .SPSM (substance painter) into blender?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

i got a good material from net but the format is .SPSM is that possible to use in blender? someone said must use plugins but i dont know what plugin it is

Comment: Probably this : https://substance3d.adobe.com/plugins/substance-in-blender/

Comment: @Emir add-ons Node: Substance 3d in blender still exist?